# How to fire a WCF callback only after the host has started

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf, mvvm

I have a WCF service, `Scheduler`, hosted within a Windows service. This host calls `StartPolling` on the WCF, inside my `OnStart` override:

```
schedulerHost = new ServiceHost(Scheduler);
schedulerHost.Open();
Scheduler.SchedulerEvent += SchedulerOnSchedulerEvent;
Scheduler.StartPolling();
```

This hosted service is started from the UI, basically in my viewmodel code. Now `StartPolling` is supposed to fire a callback to my viewmodel, notifying the viewmodel that it is now polling. But, the viewmodel can only subscribe to WCF callbacks after `OnStart` has finished, and the viewmodel sees that the host service is "Running", so it remains annoyingly unaware that the the WCF has started polling.

It looks like the cleanest way out here for the host to tell the WCF to fire a callback, but only after `OnStart` has completed. This would apparently involve a timer in the host service that fires shortly after `OnStart` exits, but how long after? I want to avoid more polling, and make this new timer only fires once. I'm trying to minimise the use of timers instead of increase it. I already have two, one running in the WCF to do scheduled processing, and one in the UI, to monitor the status of the host service.

It seems I have got this working by adding an invocation of the callback once the WCF "knows" the viewmodel has finished subscribing to the callback:

```
public void SubscribeStatusUpdate()
{
    var sub = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IEalsSchedulerCallback>();
    EventHandler channelClosed = null;
    channelClosed = delegate
        {
            statusUpdate -= sub.StatusUpdate;
        };
    OperationContext.Current.Channel.Closed += channelClosed;
    OperationContext.Current.Channel.Faulted += channelClosed;
    statusUpdate += sub.StatusUpdate;
    statusUpdate(Status);
}
```